# Dijkstras Algotithm - distance to a particular node

Tags: python, function, dijkstra

I have working code that finds the distance from my starting node to all others, producing this: 
{'0': 0, '1': 2, '2': 5, '3': 9}
What I need is a function that will allow me to input one of my nodes and return the distance given by the first function, eg inputting '3' would output 9. How would i do this?

```
import heapq

graph = {
    '0': {'1': 2, '2': 5},
    '1': {'2': 3},
    '2': {'3': 4},
    '3': {'0': 21, '1': 8},
}


def di(graph, source):
    priority_queue = []
    heapq.heappush(priority_queue, (0, source))
    visited = {}
    while priority_queue:
        (current_distance, current) = heapq.heappop(priority_queue)

        visited[current] = current_distance

        if current not in graph: continue
        for neighbour, distance in graph[current].items():

            if neighbour in visited: continue

            new_distance = current_distance + distance
            heapq.heappush(priority_queue, (new_distance, neighbour))

return visited
```

Comment: Looks like you have a dictionary composed of keys and values. ‘3’ is a key, 9 is a value. If your dictionary is d, then d[‘3’] outputs 9.

Comment: That comes up with d not being defined

Comment: It is defined because it is the output with which you are working. Why not edit your question and include your sample code (you should do that in general) for more help.

Comment: @mikey is right, you can assign the result you get from the function that you call to calculate the distance of all nodes, to a variable e.g `d`. Then calling `d['3']` will give you output `9`. You also need to include the code you use to calculate the distances.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split this array of node points and just access the last one (or the one of interest). If nothing else is applicable, you can try to split the string itself with regex and use of split character ",". This will give you an array of strings, which you will be able to access via index.
Example in java code:

```
String[] dijkstraFragments = yourString.split(",");
String nodeOfInterest = dijkstraFragments[3]; // index starts at 0
```

The output will be '3': 9 and this you can process further (convert, calculate, whatever).

Comment: I'm very new to coding and don't know what that means, or how to use your code in python.